# Find origin of the 403 error (not my server)

Tags: 403-forbidden

We are running an Apache server that provides files to several users.
Some users are getting the 403 error when trying to access any download url on our Apache.
I don't see those 403 errors in our access log.

Most of the clients are able access those urls.

I'm guessing something between the client and the Apache blocks the connection.
How do I found out who that is?

Thanks

Comment: Is there any commonality between the users that get the 403 error? And what exactly is contained in this 403 response (which presumably is not generated by your server)?

Comment: I would ask these users to do a nslookup or similar command to capture the IP address of the domain name they are seeing. It may be they are hitting someone else's machine. I have gotten requests for other servers before. It happens but it is rare.

Answer (score 2):

403 Means that the end user does not have permission to view that file.

Make sure your FTP client uploads the files with the correct permissions.

- Files: 0644
- Directories: 0755